# Python Bokeh Stacked Bar Chart not show the real value

Tags: python, bokeh

The yellow bar should always be positive, but it changed throughout time. That is really strange.[Value for the yellow bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG2Wf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKNQ6.png)

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducing example code, including any and all data necessarily to run the code.

Comment: The yellow bar may be positive, but it's starting at the end of the green bar, which is negative. It looks like the blue bar is always positive also since the blue and yellow bar hide the green when green is negative.